# Multiply two input values and display answer as paragraph on page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to take two input values from text boxes, click a button, and then return the answer as text

The two input names are "weight" and "reps". I want it so once you click the button it will do the calculation and be added to div "result"

HTML:

```
<div>
  Weight lifted: <input name="weight" type="text" value="?">
</div>
<div>
  Reps attained: <input name="reps" type="text" value="?">
</div>
<button>Calculate One-Rep Max</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

what i have now for jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var weight = $('input[name=weight]').val();
    var reps = $('input[name=weight]').val();
    var max = $('input[name=weight]').val() * $('input[name=reps]').val() * 0.0333 +   $('input[name=weight]').val();
    $('#result').append("<p>" + max + "</p>");
  });
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why are you setting variables and not using them?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Scm3R/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.val()` returns a string, and while the `*` operator implicitly converts strings to numbers (e.g. `"5.0" * "5.0"` → `25`), the `+` operator does not. The `+` at the end isn't adding the two numbers together, it's concatenating them as strings (e.g. `"5.0" + "5.0"` → `"5.05.0"`). You'll want to parse the inputs first, and then work with the results as numbers.

Try this:

```
var weight = Number($('input[name=weight]').val());
var reps = Number($('input[name=reps]').val());
var max = weight * reps * 0.0333 + weight ;
$('#result').append("<p>" + max + "</p>"); 
// or $('<p>').text(max).appendTo("#result");
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/fUA5x/)